# Trying to send data to another screen but somehow can't view it on the sent screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-drawer

So here I'm trying to send the data from home screen to reviews screen and haven't got any errors but while i'm in the reviews screen I just can't see the data that I sent

```html
//my data
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [reviews, setRevies] = useState([
    { title: 'asd', rating: 5, body: 'dsa', key: '1'},
    { title: 'asdd', rating: 3, body: 'dsaa', key: '2'},
    { title: 'asddd', rating: 4, body: 'dsaaa', key: '3'},
  ]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={reviews}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Reviews', item)}> ==> trying to send it in here
            <Text style={styles.text}>{item.title}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
const ReviewsScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{navigation.title}</Text> cannot view in this screen also tried .getParam() but says its not a function on error
    </View>
  );
};
```

tryed many thing but couldn't solve

Answer (score 0):

Passing parameters to screen is clearly documented here with good examples.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params

```
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [reviews, setRevies] = useState([
    { title: 'asd', rating: 5, body: 'dsa', key: '1'},
    { title: 'asdd', rating: 3, body: 'dsaa', key: '2'},
    { title: 'asddd', rating: 4, body: 'dsaaa', key: '3'},
  ]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={reviews}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Reviews', { item })}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{item.title}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const ReviewsScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const { item } = route.params;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{item.title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```